# Why does my Javascript converter raise a ReferenceError?

Tags: javascript, referenceerror

I developed this python app to convert turkish gold coins to ounce price for the carefull consumer. However, to publish to the web, it's required to convert it to javascript. The problem is that it raises an error:

```
ReferenceError: q is not defined.
```

Why does it raise this error and how can I fix it?

```js
// Print the welcome message
console.log('||| Welcome to our app which shows the ounce prices and optimum prices of homeland gold coins.||| \n||| Use the numbers for type of gold coins below ||| \n||| Cumhuriyet(1),Tam(2),Yarım(3),Çeyrek(4),Finish the calc and show sum(5) ||| ');
console.log('||| This is a calc which calculates the entries you have entered by order.||| \n||| To quit enter the type of gold 5 and amount of gold is any number. |||');

// Collect data from web
async function getData() {
  const url = 'https://yorum.altin.in/tum/ons';
  const headers = {
    'User_Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.88 Safari/537.36'
  };
  const page = await fetch(url, {
    headers
  });
  const content = new DOMParser().parseFromString(await page.text(), 'text/html');
  const x = content.getElementById('ofiy').innerText.trim();
  const y = content.getElementById('dfiy').innerText.trim();
  const a = parseFloat(x.substring(1, 9));
  const c = parseFloat(y.substring(0, 6));
  const ws = [0.212666471635951 * a * c, 0.206772168098369 * a * c, 0.103386084049185 * a * c, 0.0516930420245924 * a * c];
  const calcx = [];
}

// Define the main loop
async function main() {
  let q = parseInt(prompt('enter representive number of your coin: '));
  let wx = parseInt(prompt('enter amount of gold which related to q value: '));
}

// Define the function that calculates the price of the gold coins
function pr_gold() {
  if (q === 1) {
    calcx.push(ws[0] * parseInt(wx));
  } else if (q === 2) {
    calcx.push(ws[1] * parseInt(wx));
  } else if (q === 3) {
    calcx.push(ws[2] * parseInt(wx));
  } else if (q === 4) {
    calcx.push(ws[3] * parseInt(wx));
  } else if (q === 5) {
    console.log(`||| Calculation is completed. USD/TRY parity is ${c} TRY and ounce price of gold is ${a} USD |||`);
    console.log(`||| The total value of your Turkish gold coins are ${Math.ceil(calcx.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0))} TRY |||`);
  } else {
    console.log("Invalid input. Please enter a number between 1 and 5.");
  }
}

pr_gold();
```

Comment: You know, if you put your closing braces on a separate line like everyone else, it would be a lot easier to spot mismatched brace errors like this one seems to be.

Comment: You're setting `q` inside `main`, but `main` is never called, when `pr_gold` is called, `q` is undefined.

Comment: (Or maybe I'm misjudging the intent, and you really did intend to define `pr_gold` outside `main`, despite the indentation.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: if i call main(), is problem solved ?

Comment: No, variables declared with `let` have function scope. Why do you have two seperate functions `main` and `pr_gold`? I would merge `main` and `pr_gold`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with python. Please remove the irrelevant tag.

Comment: What line is the error occurring on? Please include more information.

Comment: @LawrenceWebDev It's `if (q === 1) {` in `pr_gold`

Comment: You mentioned that your code was converted from Python to Javascript. How was that done? That is to say, did you use an online service for it, or did someone write the Javascript equivalent of your original code? The reason I'm asking - if the conversion was automatic, it might be that whatever you used created bad Javascript for you, as others have mentioned in the comments.

Comment: yes. i have used chatGPT. i know its not so good idea. but idont have time learning js. i know only python. but i supposed that js is requriement for a web app.

Answer (score -1):

So you said your app is in python, and you are trying to publish it to the web, you don't have to convert your code to Javascript, you can create a WebApp/WebApi application, it is like making a website, but all the website will do is the conversion, everything else remains in python, I will suggest you go the web API route, that will be simpler, Python Has A FastAPI (https://pypi.org/project/fastapi/) module you can use, you can watch this tutorial on it, the first 8 min of the tutorial is more than enough if you still need help, let me know (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VSQZl43jFzk)

But I still got your code to work on my side, at this point the project is not a python project anymore, I won't recommend you continue on this path but here is the code if you feel like seeing how it will work.

This is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head >
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
The content of the document......
</body>
    
<script>
    // Print the welcome message
console.log('||| Welcome to our app which shows the ounce prices and optimum prices of homeland gold coins.||| \n||| Use the numbers for type of gold coins below ||| \n||| Cumhuriyet(1),Tam(2),Yarım(3),Çeyrek(4),Finish the calc and show sum(5) ||| ');
console.log('||| This is a calc which calculates the entries you have entered by order.||| \n||| To quit enter the type of gold 5 and amount of gold is any number. |||');

// Collect data from web
async function getData() {
    const cors_bypass = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/"; //Had to add this line because I was getting a CORS error
    const url = cors_bypass + 'https://yorum.altin.in/tum/ons';
    const headers = { 'User_Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.88 Safari/537.36','method' : "GET", 'Accept': '*/*', 'mode':'no-cors'};
    console.log(headers);
    const page = await fetch(url, { headers });
    const content = new DOMParser().parseFromString(await page.text(), 'text/html');
    const x = content.getElementById('ofiy').innerText.trim();
    const y = content.getElementById('dfiy').innerText.trim();
    const a = parseFloat(x.substring(1, 9));
    const c = parseFloat(y.substring(0, 6));
    const ws = [0.212666471635951 * a * c, 0.206772168098369 * a * c, 0.103386084049185 * a * c, 0.0516930420245924 * a * c];
    const calcx = [];
    return { "calcx" : calcx, "ws" : ws, "c":c};
}

        // Define the function that calculates the price of the gold coins
        // Define the main loop
    async function main() {
        let q = parseInt(prompt('enter representive number of your coin: '));
        let wx = parseInt(prompt('enter amount of gold which related to q value: '));
        return { "q" : q , "wx" : wx};
    }
    
    function pr_gold( q , wx , calcx, ws, c) {
            console.log(q);
            if (q === 1) {
                calcx.push(ws[0] * parseInt(wx));}
            else if (q === 2) {
                calcx.push(ws[1] * parseInt(wx));}
            else if (q === 3) {
                calcx.push(ws[2] * parseInt(wx));}
            else if (q === 4) {
                calcx.push(ws[3] * parseInt(wx));}
            else if (q === 5) {
                console.log(`||| Calculation is completed. USD/TRY parity is ${c} TRY and ounce price of gold is ${a} USD |||`);
                console.log(`||| The total value of your Turkish gold coins are ${Math.ceil(calcx.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0))} TRY |||`);}
            else {
                console.log("Invalid input. Please enter a number between 1 and 5.");}
        }

        var getdata_results = {};
        getData().then((result) =>{
                    getdata_results = result; 
                    //console.log(result);
                    main().then((results) => {
                                        main_results = results; 
                                        //console.log(results);
                                        pr_gold( main_results["q"], main_results["wx"], getdata_results["calcx"], getdata_results["ws"], getdata_results["c"]);
                                    });
                } );
    
        
        

</script>

</html>
```

When I run the code, I inputted 2 and 2 for q and wx and I got the following :
[image]

So the above code works for the input q=2 and wx=2 other inputs might give you an error, but I am still debugging it. let me know if you are interested in the refined code that works for all scenarios. The following inputs q=5 and wx=2 will give you an error, just saying before you think my code does not work, I fixed the code to work on the bare minimum.

Yeah, So I Got A CORS Error, if you run my code and also get the CORS error, visit this site https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/corsdemo there will be a button that says "request temporary access to demo server" click it then rerun the code.

Due to the fact that you made your functions async, I had to use the ".then()" notation to get this to work, I would suggest you learn about async stuff, anyone reading this should please link to some async materials. It's good to use async but first make sure you need it, I feel like I can write this code in a more beginner-friendly manner without async.

Looking at the code, it looks like whoever wrote it hasn't yet grasped the workings of variable scopes, the user @jabaa https://stackoverflow.com/users/16540390/jabaa posted a link to materials on JS async stuff, I will just post it here for convenience

> Does this answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript

Yeah, So any further questions, post below, looking at the code, I feel like whoever wrote this code needs 1 or 2 weeks more of tutorials into the Javascript Basics.

I did not explain much of the changes I did, because well, it will be like I am writing documentation, and that's not my favorite thing to do, so post in the comment below as to whether I should explain my changes, then I will do it ( i will only do that if the request comes from @lex ).

Comment: i decided to make it by restapi. now, a am learning it. thank you for intense interest.

Comment: restapi is a great choice, I would appreciate it if you marked my response as the answer to your question. @lex

Comment: @lex i happy that i could help, now I am going to recommend some changes to your question, I would suggest you change the title to "How to put my python program on the web" and then add python in the tags , oh and please mark this question as resolved by marking a response as an answer.